# hapi-swagger disables my routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Below is the glue manifest I use to fire up the server:

```
var Config = require('../config.json');

var internals = {
    manifest: {
        connections: [
        {
            host    : Config.host || process.env.IP,
            port    : Config.apiPort || process.env.PORT,
            labels  : ['api']
        }],
        plugins: {
            './decorate': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            'hapi-auth-jwt': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            './authentication': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            './controllers': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            './models': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            './api': [{ 'select': ['api']}],
            good: {
                opsInterval: 5000,
                reporters: [
                    { 'reporter': 'good-console', 'events': { 'log': '*' } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
if (!process.env.PRODUCTION) {
    internals.manifest.plugins['blipp'] = [{}];
    internals.manifest.plugins['good'].reporters[0].events['ops'] =  '*';
}

module.exports = internals.manifest;
```

As soon as I add 'hapi-swagger' to the list of plugins the server stops responding to the routes defined in the ./api file. None of the routes work. Is the the right way to add hapi-swagger to the glue manifest or am I doing something absurd?

EDIT: Below is the api.js

```
exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {

    plugin.dependency('controllers');
    plugin.dependency('models');

    var Controllers = plugin.plugins.controllers.handlers;
    var Models = plugin.plugins.models.models;
    plugin.bind({
        models: Models
    });

    plugin.route([
        { method: 'GET',    path: '/token',             config: Controllers.Membership.token },

        { method: 'GET',    path: '/',                  config: Controllers.Home.status },
        { method: 'GET',    path: '/nodes',             config: Controllers.Node.search },
        { method: 'GET',    path: '/services',          config: Controllers.Node.services },

        { method: 'GET',    path: '/createnodetree',    config: Controllers.Loader.createNodeTree }
    ]);

    next();
};



exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'api',
    version: require('../package.json').version
};
```

Comment: What does your `api.js` file look like?

Comment: What versions of hapi and hapi-swagger are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you try to use hapi-swagger without either including the documentation view dependencies or properly disabling documentation support. From the [docs](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger#install):

> If you want to view the documentation from your API you will also need to install the inert and vision plugs-ins which support templates and static content serving. If you wish just to used swagger.json without the documentation for example with swagger-codegen simply set options.enableDocumentation to false.

You didn't show how you are adding the hapi-swagger plugin but you simply need to add `'enableDocumentation': false` to options wherever you define that. You can find examples at the link above.